# Brunch build tool: subfolders in the assets directory are not copied?

Tags: brunch

i'm trying to set up my first project using Brunch, and i'm having a small issue, i want brunch to copy all files and subfolders in `assets/` to the `public/` folder, but it only copies the files and ignores the subfolders and other files.

And another thing is that i might like to have a folder called `styles` with subfolders for images and fonts, and i want them to be copied to the same place but in the `public/` folder, is that possible?

here is an example:

```
app/
    -assets/    html files, some xml files and ico's too
    -styles/
        -scss/
        -img/
        -fonts/
    -scripts/
    -vendor/    js and css files.
```

target folder:

```
public/        all files from assets
    -styles    css from scss folder, and a css for vendor's css
        -img
        -fonts
    -js        vendor and app js files
```

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brunch only handles assets inside `assets` folders by default. You can also create `app/styles/assets` subdirectory.

If you want to change this default behavior, it's possible to change [config.conventions.assets](http://brunch.io/docs/config#-conventions-).